# Regexp Substr in Teradata

Tags: teradata, regexp-substr

I have text in a column like `'/T$ABC$DEF$T12M5UU$S1$XXXYYY$122F370'` and I am trying to extract just 122F370. I used the below function to extract just the 7 characters after the last $  that but it gives me an error. Can someone please help?
This is what I am using currently

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT,'^([^$]*$){6}\K.......',1,1,'i')
```

Comment: Are there always 6 `$`?

Comment: Most of the time. If not I would just need the last 7 characters at end of the text followed by the last $

Answer (score 0):

In a RegEx `$` means *end of the string*. Of course, there's only one of them :-)

You must mask it with `\`:

```
RegExp_Substr(TXT,'^([^$]*\$){6}\K.{7}',1,1,'i')
```

To extract always the last 7 characters:

```
RegExp_Substr(TXT,'.{7}$',1,1,'i')
```

If there's always some characters between those `$` you can also use

```
StrTok(TXT,'$', 7)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked. I will use both the REGEXP_SUBSTR in my query just to be safe